# Pure SVG Javascript library

Tags: html, svg

I'm looking for a library that speeds up writing of HTML5 SVG, and manipulating the objects. I want something that can leverage the power of all SVG features.

I was using Raphael but annoyingly it (severely) limits functionality to that of VML. I don't care about cross-browser compatibility, I just want a full javascript abstraction of SVG. I don't care about conversion to flash, I don't care about conversion to 2d Canvas, ... you get the picture!

What options are there? Or should I just get used to raw SVG declarations and manipulation?

Thanks

Comment: Raphael is a very strongly built SVG library, if its functions are limited, going with pure Javascript+SVG might be the right way.

Comment: I think I'll give Keith Wood's JQuery SVG a go

Comment: jQuery SVG is not a library, its an extension to enables several functionality of jquery especially its selector ability to be applied on SVG elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graphics generate, in some way or another, from data, I would give D3.js a try.

Even if the data weight of your needs is low, I think that it can be very useful to give it a look.

On the plus side is that it generates absolutely standard svg, style with standard css, so you can check what is happening easily. You could even use it to generate svg, and then copy/paste your svg to another project without the D3.js.

Another plus is the support for transitions, that is very good imho.

[link](http://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 4):

There's a new compact library called [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/) that offers easier svg manipulation, and which doesn't have any VML legacy code/restrictions like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) has.